# Getting UTF 8 encoded data from a web server

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, http-headers, apache-nifi

My data pipeline is ->

> WebServer -> Data Ingestion through PipeLine -> Solr

Using GetHTTP processor in Nifi, I am reading from the web server. The processor is working with `Accept Content-Type = content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`. However, when I load this in Solr,  I see strange characters.

When the file is downloaded through browser (from web server), i see a different set of strange characters (both on browser window and on an editor like notepad++)

All across the pipeline, i am working with UTF 8 character set only.

What could be the reason of seeing different characters in solr, browser and on the downloaded file (notepad++ - encoded to UTF 8)

Comment: could you store file (PutFile) after GetHTTP and publish it in question? also you said you can download file with browser. could you compare files ? or publihs the second file also..

Answer (score 0):

I use InvokeHTTP instead of GetHTTP or any other processor to do some similar http actions.
InvokeHTTP cloud help you to find out the details. Use this processor and save the response in a file share this file we cloud help you. Or you can change the debug lv in the processor then look up the log.